# selenium web driver : Able to open Firefox browser but The address isn’t valid

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
```

Says "Invalid address"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
```

Comment: check with driver.get("url"); does it works manually good

Comment: Yes, I check the URL manually it worked and I copied the url and pasted still I am not able to open the URL in the browser. I tried different URL also

Answer (score 1):

Replace ,

```
driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
```

with

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

As per your code block:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
```

This should have worked.

To open a url (considering the url of `String` type) you can consider to use any of the other two methods as follows:

1. Use `get()` method to open the url:

   ```
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.get("https://www.google.com");
   ```
2. Use `Navigation` class to create a new object and open url:

   ```
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   Navigation sara_navigate = driver.navigate();
   sara_navigate.to("https://www.google.com");
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thank you Debanjan for answering my question till I get the problem in loading page

Comment: The command opens the browser and when it try's to open the URL then it show invalid address

Comment: @SaraR I think it's an issue with the Browser. Can you consider the following: 1) Uninstall your Browser. 2) Delete all the dangling instances of drivers from `Task Manager` 3) If possible use CCleaner to wipe away all the rotten stuffs from your PC. 4) Install recent GA release of Chrome 58.0 or Mozilla 53.0 and execute your script. Let me know the status. Thanks

Comment: @SaraR After all the mentioned steps consider to restart your system once before installing the new browsers & execute the script. Thanks